# sub patch generation mechanism for training fully convolutional neural network

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

I have a image set, consisting of 300 image pairs, i.e., raw image and mask image. A typical mask image is shown as follows. Each image has size of 800*800. I am trying to train a fully convolutional neural network model for this image set to perform the semantic segmentation. I am trying to generate the small patches (256*256) from the original images for constructing the training set. Are there any strategies recommended for this patch sampling process? Naturally, random sampling is a trivial approach. Here the area marked with yellow, foreground class, usually take 25% of the whole image area across the image set. It tends to reflect an imbalanced data set.

[image: image example]

Comment: why sample patches? why not work with the entire image and maybe sample pixels for the loss?

Comment: There are only 300 image pairs, which represent a too small data set for training FCN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you train a fully convolutional architecture, assuming `800x800` inputs and `25x25` outputs (after five `2x2` pooling layers, `25=800/2^5`).  Try to build the `25x25` outputs directly and train directly on them.  You can add higher weights in the loss function for the "positive" labels to balance them with the "negative".

I definitely do not recommend sampling because it will be an expensive process and is not really fully convolutional.

Comment: Hi MZhm, what do you mean training directly on 25*25 outputs? If we do not use sampling process, we only have 300 image pairs, is that a too small data set for training deep learning model? Besides, for FCN-based semantic segmentation, the output should be the same size as the input.

Comment: For upsampling back to the original image size, I suggest that your read about `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose`.  For the sampling, there is no benefit of doing that over training on the full image. (remember that the output is not a single prediction, it is a spatial grid of 25x25 predictions in the example above)

Comment: As for the question if 300 is enough... There is only one way to check - train and test it